# Drop the iteration with warning in a loop

Tags: r, loops, warnings

In R, I need to fulfill a set in a loop, but sometimes the calculation will generate warnings, I want to get rid of any result with warning, so the final result will without any element with warnings. For example:

```
result <- numeric(10)
for (i in 1:length(result)){
 element <- sample(-1:1,1)
 result[i] <- log(element)
}
```

You can see when `element=-1`, `log(element)=NaN`,`NaN` will still store to `result` while R will give a warning. I just want to avoid such`NaN`stored to `result` based on warning. This is a an easy situation, we can have other option. But the situation I have to face is much more complex. So I hope I can find a method that if there is warning happened, so we will get rid of the result from calculation with warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `tryCatch()` and combine this with a recursion to avoid warning messages and `NaN` entries:

```
set.seed(222) # for reproducibility of the pseudo-random results
set_to_log <- function() {
  element <- sample(-1:2,1)
  tryCatch(log(element), warning = function(w) set_to_log())
}
result <- numeric(10)
for (i in 1:length(result)){
  result[i] <- set_to_log()
}
#> result
# [1] 0.6931472      -Inf 0.6931472 0.6931472      -Inf      -Inf 0.0000000      -Inf 0.0000000 0.6931472
```

Here, the `function(w)` specifies that the function `set_to_log()` should be called again in the case of a warning, which would occur if an `NaN` result is generated. By using `tryCatch()` with this recursion, the code will not give any warning and the vector`result` will not contain any `NaN` entries. The `result` vector may however contain `-Inf` entries, which correspond to the cases of `log(0)` and are produced without warning.

Comment: RHertel, thanks for your reply. `tryCatch()` looks like the function I should use. The only problem is that I do not want to skip any iteration, I just want to make sure all the element in the result vector without any warning message. In your example, if my understanding is correct, the useful result would be less than 10?

Comment: You need to decide what should be stored in the vector in the case of a `NaN`. This situation occurs in your example when you try to take the logarithm of a negative number. In that case the result is not defined. What should be stored in the vector? If `NaN` is alright as an entry in the vector, but you are just disturbed by the warnings printed while the script runs, you can use `try(result[i] <- log(element), silent=TRUE)` (in that case the warnings will be printed *after* the script has run).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. When a `NaN` is generated, I just want to run `element <- sample(-1:1,1); result[i] <- log(element)` again until an result without any warning generated. I am trying to use some `while` loop to achieve my target.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think that in this case a recursion could help. I updated the post accordingly and expanded the range of sampling somewhat to increase the diversity of acceptable results. Does this correspond to what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks, RHertel. Recursion is what I am looking for! Can I ask a question about a detail in your first version code. In that code, it looks like `i=i+1` let `tryCatch()` function have the ability to move to the next iteration. However, it seems that we do not have to use `i=i+1`. If I use `j=1` instead of `i=i+1`, the code will work in same way even `j` is not defined in anywhere. So I assume `function(w)` is just a warning handler, it does not actually change the value of `i` in my loop, am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: I think that you're right. The part with `i <- i+1` in my previous version was probably useless and `function(w)` was just capturing the warning. It is also a line of code that you will hardly see in R codes, unlike the ubiquitous `i+=1` or something like this which is ubiquuitous in other languages. Sorry if this has caused confusion; I guess I'm still influenced by other languages that I used before learning R, from Fortran to C to C++. In any case I'm glad that now the code does what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for all your time and knowledge on this. You really help me a lot!